# noHistory Intent flag doesn't work on Android 7

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-7.0-nougat, back-stack

I've got the Activity "A" and I start an Activity "B" using the `android:noHistory="true"` flag from the AndroidManifest to prevent B to be in the stack after going to the next Activity "C" because I don't want the user to go back to B when pressing the back button (they should go back directly to A).

It was working fine, but now for Android 7 (only) it's failing if I press the back button very quickly after reaching C. It seems like a race condition between the user's back input and the process that destroys the Activity B because of the flag.

There are 2 possible hotfix but both of them have problems:

1. Call `finish()` after calling `startActivity()`.

   Doing this has performance problems on Android 6 and Motorola phones because the destroy process is being executed at the same time than the C creation process.
2. Call `finish()` on `onResume()` to finish B after going back from C.

   This is a hotfix, but is **not** a good solution. The `noHistory` flag should do it by itself.

Do you have any suggestion?

Regards!

Comment: It happens to me as well in samsung s8 device, did you find any work around?
Thanks

Comment: Hi! No, I'm using the hotfix nº 2 for the moment. Please let me know if you find any other solution! Regards!